# ActiveMQ auto-generating empty queues

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I have an ActiveMQ broker (version 5.14.3) running, which is being used by producers and consumers of different origins.

For some reason recently a lot of empty queues have been automatically created labeled either `communication_{SOME_HASH}` or `communication_{NAME_OF_ORIGIN_MACHINE}_{SOME_PROCESS_ID}`. These queues are all empty queues without any enqueued or dequeued messages, which I assume are useless but are still generated for some reason.

Has somebody come across the same issue and can either explain why these queues are being generated or point out how I can avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not prefixes for any type of temporary or advisory based destinations that ActiveMQ would ever create so the fault must lay in your own application.  You would need to debug this from your own side to find out where they are coming from.  Since ActiveMQ creates destinations whenever a Producer or Consumer is created on a Topic or Queue unless security policies prevent that your applications may be creating these resources accidentally an never using them.